# Eliminate Humidistat

Tags: hvac

I have an old Honeywell H8808 humidistat and a Pro 1 model T721 thermostat and the problem is that when the humidistat is turned down far enough to kick the system on it will come down to set temperatures and the condensing unit will shut off but the blower will keep running. If you turn up the humidistat the blower will go off but the system won’t kick on again when the temperature rises above the thermostat setting. I’ve tried every combinations of settings that I could think of with no luck. Is there a way to just eliminate the humidistat which I really don’t need?

Comment: Have you unwired the humistat from ac or tstat

Comment: If I unwire the humidistat the system won’t work at all.